# Python How to write 5 lines in one file.txt and the other 3 lines in a new file1.txt with +=1 for example

Tags: python, file, for-loop, while-loop, line

I would like a script generating 12 lines in total.
5 lines in one file Numbers.txt
5 lines in a second file Numbers0001.txt
2 lines in the Third file Numbers0002.txt

Has anyone dealt with this before and could help me ?

My working code to insert 5 lines according to the user input:

```
import random
import string

oneFile = open('‪Numbers.txt', 'w')
userInput = 0
key_count = 0
value_count = 0
chars = string.ascii_uppercase

for userInput in range(int(input('How many 12 digit keys do you want?'))):
    while key_count <= userInput:
        key_count += 1
        number = random.randint(1, 999)
        key = number

        text = str(''.join(random.sample(chars*6, 12)))
        oneFile.write(text + "\n")
oneFile.close()
```

**Here the code I'm struggling on with my loop and my If Else:**

```
import random
import string


userInput = 0
key_count = 0
value_count = 0
chars = string.ascii_uppercase

if key_count > 5:
    for userInput in range(int(input('How many 8 digit keys do you want?'))):
        while key_count <= userInput:
                            oneFile = open(key_count('.txt', 'w'))
                            key_count += 1
                            number = random.randint(1, 999)
                            key = number
                            text = str(''.join(random.sample(chars*6, 8)))
                            oneFile.write(text + "\n")
                            oneFile.close()
else:
    oneFile = open('‪Numbers'+ +=1 +'.txt', 'w')
    oneFile.write(text + "\n") +5
    oneFile.close()
```

Comment: Why do you have a ```key = number``` line?  Can't you just use the number variable you've already defined?

Comment: I don't see where the 12 lines of keys come from when you have a user input asking how many they want? Do you want the user to only want 12 keys at a time max?

Comment: oneFile = open('‪Numbers'+ +=1 +'.txt', 'w') this is not working. if you want to have  a number in there then create a counter variable and +1 it outside the open and use the variable line oneFile = open("Numbers" + my_var + ".txt", "w")

Comment: also in the else: there is not text variable you are trying to use. text is only there if key_count > 5

Comment: the question does not allign with your code  - you want to generate 12 lines or have a person input 12 lines? Anyway i would save the 12 lines in a list and then iterate over the list and making an if/elif/else logic that writes the lines into the correct file using some counter.

Comment: Indeed MarxMarcher, your input led me on the way, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is what you were looking for. 
I just took a list of 12 items (ints from 1-12) and put them into three files Number.txt Numbers001.txt and Numbers002.txt

```
list_of_something = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

counter = 0
while counter < len(list_of_something):
    if counter < 5:

        oneFile = open("Numbers.txt", 'a')
        oneFile.write(str(list_of_something[counter]) + "\n")
        oneFile.close()
        counter +=1

    elif counter >=5 and counter < 10:
        oneFile = open("Numbers001.txt", 'a')
        oneFile.write(str(list_of_something[counter]) + "\n")
        oneFile.close()
        counter +=1

    else:
        oneFile = open("Numbers002.txt", 'a')
        oneFile.write(str(list_of_something[counter]) + "\n")
        oneFile.close()
        counter +=1
```

Output of this will be then 3 files - first will have 1-5th second 6-10th and third 11-12th item from the list

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string


userInput = 0
key_count = 0
file_count = 0
value_count = 0
chars = string.ascii_uppercase

for userInput in range(int(input('How many 8 digit keys do you want?'))):
    while key_count <= userInput:

        if key_count % 5 == 0:
            file_count += 1
            oneFile = open('‪Numbers000'+ str(file_count) +'.txt', 'w')

        key_count += 1
        number = random.randint(1, 999)
        key = number

        text = str(''.join(random.sample(chars*6, 8)))
        oneFile.write(text + "\n")

        if key_count % 5 == 0:
                                    oneFile.close()
```